# xsd validation for tag value not null

Tags: xml, tags, xsd, xsd-validation

My Xml is :

```
    <LineService>
        <LineSrId>SR_CP_JD_144084-1</LineSrId>
        <MSNumber/>
        <AccountNo>1320116817829261</AccountNo>
    </LineService>
```

And my xsd is :

```
<element name="LineService" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element type="string" name="LineSrId" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
            <element name="MSISDN" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true">
                <simpleType>
                    <restriction base="string">
                        <pattern value="\d{10,18}|"></pattern>
                    </restriction>
                </simpleType>
            </element>
            <element type="string" name="AccountNo" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

I want to check MS Number or Account No can be null but both should not be null for a request. At least one of them should be not null and having values.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a xsd definition to make `<AccountNo>` or `<MSNumber>` or both but not any valid. The usual way to do so is combining `<xs:choice>`, `<xs:sequence>`and minOccurs attribute. Please note that in your xsd your element name is MSISDN and in your XML is MSNumber, I use MSNumber as in your XML, here is my solution:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
...
<element name="AccountNo" type="string"/>
<element name="MSNumber">
    <simpleType>
        <restriction base="string">
            <pattern value="\d{10,18}|"></pattern>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
</element>
<element name="LineService" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element type="string" name="LineSrId" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="MSNumber"/>
                    <xs:element ref="AccountNo" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="AccountNo"/>
            </xs:choice>            
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
...
</schema>
```

Hope this help,